# How to prevent multiple slidetoggles on the same item

Tags: jquery, accordion, slidetoggle

I currently have list with a sub UL. When clicking on a list item, I want the UL to slide toggle. This I have achieved. The issue I'm currently having is, if i click on the same item that I have opened to close it, it performs a double toggle. It's worth mentioning, that I would like only one sub ul to be open at a time.

**HTML**

```
<div class="top">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#"> Item </a></li>
<li class="drop"><a href="#"> Item Drop </a>
  <ul class="sub">
    <li><a href="#"> Sub Item </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Sub Item </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Sub Item </a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#"> Item </a></li>
<li><a href="#"> Item </a></li>
<li class="drop"><a href="#"> Item Drop</a>
  <ul class="sub">>
    <li><a href="#"> Sub Item </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Sub Item </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Sub Item </a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
  li {
    ul {
      display:none;
    }
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.drop').click(function(){
  $('.sub').slideUp();
  $(this).children('.sub').slideToggle();
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRZPvZ

Comment: remove `$('.sub').slideUp();`

Comment: Bugger. I should have mentioned that I want all the others to slide up when an item is clicked on, so that only one is ever shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
$('.drop').click(function(e){
  if($(e.target).closest('ul').is(':not(.sub)')) {//if the clicked element is has a ul that is not .sub we slide them up
  $('.sub').slideUp();}
  $(this).children('.sub').slideToggle();
});
```

or:

```
$('.drop').click(function(e){
  $('.sub').not( $(this).children('.sub')).slideUp();//hide all except the one we want to display
  $(this).children('.sub').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Thank you a million Madalin. Very kind.